# Running Javascript in every occurence in while loop

Tags: php

so i have this while loop to display checkbox for each column in a row. I am having problem that the javascript doesnt run in every row. The jquery only runs at the first while iteration. Please, i need an advise on how to run the jquery on every iteration.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#cuttingCheckbox').change(function() {
         if (this.checked) {
           alert('checked');
         } else {
           alert('unchecked');
         }
       });

    $('#assemblyCheckbox').change(function() {
         if (this.checked) {
           alert('checked');
         } else {
           alert('unchecked');
         }
       }); 

    </script>

<?php                

// IF SHOW KEY HAS BEEN PRESSED
if($_POST['action'] == 'show')
    {            
    $sql   = "SELECT * FROM SUB_MASTER_DRAWING
                      WHERE SUB_MASTER_DRAWING.HEAD_MARK = '{$_POST["hm"]}'";

    $query = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
            $query_exec = oci_execute($query);

           echo "<table border='1'>";
    while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($query)){

                            echo "<tr><td><b>$row[HEAD_MARK]/$row[ID]</b></td>";

                                      if ($row['CUTTING'] == 'Y'){                                   
                                          echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='cuttingCheckbox'  name='cuttingCheckbox' checked='checked' disabled='disabled'/></td>";
                                      } else {
                                          echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='cuttingCheckbox'  name='cuttingCheckbox' /></td>";
                                      }   


                                      if ($row['ASSEMBLY'] == 'Y'){                                   
                                          echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='assemblyCheckbox'  name='check' checked='checked' disabled='disabled'/></td>";
                                      } else {
                                          echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='assemblyCheckbox'  name='check' /></td>";
                                      }
```

Comment: This is really a PHP problem, not a javascript or ajax problem.

Comment: You have `n` number of `id="cuttingCheckbox"` and `n` number of `id='assemblyCheckbox'`. Since `id`s are supposed to be `unique`, your javascript will only work on the first instance, since it will only look for it once. Change these to a class.

Comment: so you mean i should do like this,

<input type='checkbox' class='assemblyCheckbox'  name='check' /> ??

Comment: Yes, and then in your javascript change from an id selector (`#`) to a class selector (`.`)